# Outputting variables within a plugin

Tags: expressionengine

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/17814936), I'm now trying to rework the plugin so that I can do:

```
{exp:deetector}
     {user_agent}
     {hash}
{/exp:deetector}
```

but with the code below, I get no output:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->EE =& get_instance();

    include(PATH_THIRD.'/deetector/libraries/detector.php');

    $this->ua = $ua;

    $tagdata = $this->EE->TMPL->tagdata;

    $variables[] = array(
        'user_agent'   => $this->ua->ua,
        'hash'         => $this->ua->uaHash,
        'browser_os'   => $this->ua->full,
        'browser'      => $this->ua->browser,
        'browser_full' => $this->ua->browserFull
    );

    return $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables($tagdata, $variables);
}
```

If I do `$this->return_data = $this->ua->xx` for each of the variables listed above I get output, but not if I parse the $variables array.

I've also tried `$variables = array` but get *Undefined offset: 0*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're just using the *constructor* for output, make sure the plugin class has a public property `return_data` which contains the parsed tagdata:

```
$this->return_data = $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables($tagdata, $variables);
```

For any other method in the class, you can just simply return the parsed data, as per your example.

As a sidenote, I take it you're not looping any data here. Consider using the `parse_variables_row` method instead, so extra variables like `count`, `total_results` and `switch` are omitted. Using that method doesn't require a nested array, so it would come down to this:

```
$variables = array(
    'user_agent' => $this->ua->ua,
    ...
);

$this->return_data = $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables_row($tagdata, $variables);
```

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more on _make sure the plugin class has a public property return_data which contains the parsed tagdata_ ? Because if I have `public $return_data = $something_else` I get _unexpected T_VARIABLE_.

Comment: It should be defined as a class property, not necessarily in the method itself. Just leaving it as `$this->return_data = 'whatever';` will work fine as well.

Comment: Thanks, making it `$this->return_data = $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables_row($tagdata, $variables);` has done the trick. :)

Comment: @Low - Will using `parse_variables_row()` prevent the variables from being used in conditionals? e.g. `{if user_agent = "blah"}`

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the other post you referenced, nobody pointed out that you had defined 2 constructor functions:

```
__construct() and deetector()
```

You should drop the second one and just `use __construct()`.  Not sure if that's possibly causing the strange PHP errors.

Comment: I've actually removed that function in this version.

Comment: That was pointed out in my answer on the other question. Don't think it was causing this particular problem, but it could definitely cause unexpected behaviour.

Comment: You could use both, as long as only this is in the `deetector()` method: `return $this->__construct();`